# Как посмотреть исходный код утилиты в linux?

Tags: python, linux, reverse-engineering

Можно ли посмотреть исходный код какой-либо утилиты в линукс не заходя на гитхаб или другой интернет ресурс. Как это можно сделать сразу в операционной системе? Можно ли с помощью nano открыть?

Comment: Нельзя, нафига системе тратить место на диске ради хранения никому не нужных исходников

Comment: Ну можно включить репозиторий с исходниками и скачать их. Для Debian/Ubuntu см команду `apt-get source` (первая попавшаяся инструкция https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-get-source-code-of-package-using-the-apt-command-on-debian-or-ubuntu/)

Comment: а если есть утилиты на интерпретируемых языках то их как посмотреть через редактор кода?

Comment: @AlexeyTen такого репозитория может и не существовать

Comment: @ushiYT-майнкрафт просто берёте и открываете эту утилиту в редакторе

Comment: @andreymal, да. Но это обычно сторонние репозитории. Базовые есть практически у всех.

Answer (score 0):

опенсорс можно поискать в репах на гитхабе или на сайтах, которые поддерживают софт, если язык интерпретируемый и софт написан на чем то типа питона, то на гитхабе, гитлабе, etc в большинстве случаев есть репы наиболее популярных утилит.

Софт для реверс инжениринга: IDA Pro (платная), Ghidra, Cutter, можно посмотреть исходники, но если код закрытый, то это противоречит лицензии и могут быть различные [препятствия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))